# javascript find td second row using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get second row and value in class name
using (javascript)

```
 var doneData=$('#datatable_fixed_column tr').find('.donex').eq(1).text();
    alert(doneData);
```

but its not working here is sample of table (html)

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr class="codexTotal" >
    <th > 1 </th>
    <th >2</th>
    <th >3</th>
    <th >4</th>
    <th >5</th>
    <th class="donex">6</th>
    <th class="hider waitx">7</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="codexTotal">
    <td >data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
    <td>data5</td>
    <td class="donex">Get this data</td>
    <td class="hider waitx">Get this data</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure?

Comment: You have only one element with the class "donex" so what do you need the `.eq()` for?

Comment: ah yes sory im using datatables jquery, in the sample there's suppose to be class=donex in  <th >6</th>, i must've delete it when i tried to copy fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to solve the problem, by using .dataTable().fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.push, this will detect changes in the datatable, first i generate the id

```
                    { "data": "1" },
                    { "data": "2" },
                    { "data": "3" },
                    { "data": "4" },
                    { "data": "5" },

                    {
                        "className": 'hider',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                            return '<div id="donerx'+meta.row+'">'+row['getData1']+'</div>'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "className": 'hider',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                            return '<div id="waitrx'+meta.row+'">'+row['getData2']+'</div>'
                        }
                    }
```

then i add the function, to find what i need

```
 $('#datatable_fixed_column').dataTable().fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.push({
                "fn": function () {

            var donerx = document.getElementById("donerx0").textContent;
                   alert(donerx);

                }
            });
```